# Conditional subnav display with Taxonomy

Tags: navigation, taxonomy

I have a tree like this:

```
About Us
 - Alpha
 - Beta
 - Delta
  * Three Sub 1
  * Three Sub 2
Careers
  - Full time
```

When the current page is 'Beta', since 'Beta' does not have any child entries *and* is at the second level of navigation, I want to hide my navigation breadcrumbs.

I have the breadcrumbs displaying fine, but how would I use a condition to check that a node is both at a certain level, and also has no children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information about any node via [the get_node tag](http://iain.co.nz/software/docs/taxonomy3-get-node).

From there, you can find out if the node has children, as well as the depth of the current node.

Something like:

```
{exp:taxonomy:get_node tree_id="1" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    {if this_node_level > 2 && this_node_has_children}
        {exp:taxonomy:breadcrumbs tree_id="1" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    {/if}
{/exp:taxonomy:get_node}
```